# WP Archive & Category Pages not filtering

Tags: archives, categories

I'm going bananas. I'm creating custom archive pages for a client because whoever originally developed their site didn't create any.

I've got the pages there and working like they should, but it's not showing the appropriate posts per whatever category/tag page we're on.

Here's my code snippet boiled down:

```
    <?php
  $args = array ( 'category' => single_cat_title(), 'posts_per_page' => 5);
  $myposts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach( $myposts as $post ) :    setup_postdata($post);
   ?>
  <li>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time with this today. Geez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [codex for get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

> The category parameter needs to be the ID of the category, and not the category name.

So you should either use `category_name` parameter with name or you could pass the ID to `category`.

```
<?php
  $term_name = get_queried_object()->name;
  $args = array ( 'category_name' => $term_name, 'posts_per_page' => 5);
  $myposts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach( $myposts as $post ) :    setup_postdata($post);
   ?>
  <li>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

or

```
<?php
  $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
  $args = array ( 'category' => $term_id, 'posts_per_page' => 5);
  $myposts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach( $myposts as $post ) :    setup_postdata($post);
   ?>
  <li>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: Should this work for tags and categories the same?

Comment: For tags you should do a `tax_query =>array(array())`, I think. Check the get_posts Codex, though. It's in there. Also, in my opinion it's easier to do custom archives using the built in [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/). Then you don't need to use `get_posts()` at all. Just use

`while(have_posts()) : the_post(); get_template_part('content','TERM'); endwhile;`

in a file named `tag-TERMSLUG.php`.

Comment: Your second code worked like a charm for the category pages. I'm still having issues with the tag pages. The template hierarchy isn't much help because of the lack of templates that were originally developed for this custom theme. It's obnoxious. 

Any more hints for the tag pages? I'm not sure I'm familiar enough to translate your last comment into workable code.

Comment: If you have an `archive.php` template, just duplicate it and rename it `tag.php`. You can customize that to apply to all tag archives. If you want to customize a specific tag, like "music," then duplicate the `tag.php` template and name it `tag-music.php`.